# multiple location in nginx is not working - error 404

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am trying to run two nodejs app one on default path **(/)** and another on **/api** , I have tried multiple ways but multiple locations are not working with nginx , only root domain **(/)** works fine,  it doesn't matter which app I do assign (2nd or first). and if I try to visit **(/api)** it return 404 not found and **(/)** path is working fine.
Here is my default nginx file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;

    location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong. Any help will be apricated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Doing a lot of googling and tried many ways I have found the solution and instead of using react app as dynamic loading i generated a build of react and stored that build on a particular location and served these build files on main location with nginx.

```
location / {
            root /home/user/gui/build;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
   
location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

location /static/ {
        root  /home/user/gui;
        try_files
            /gui/build$uri
            =404;
    }
```

So here **(/)** will try files in the **root** folder which is here *(/home/user/gui/build)* and we have index.html which is generated by **react build** this **index.html** will be served. Now the next problem was to serve react generated static files so i have created a separate location *(/static/)* with the same logic of / path.